# Problem handling custom Active Directory date attribute

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, schema, directoryservices

I have extended our schema with a new attribute of type large integer/interval to be used as a date. There are issues here. One is that in `ADUC`, the attribute shows as a number while other dates in the system (with same underlying type) show up as a date. That seems to be ok, actually, since it is integer. Maybe `ADUC` has preset some attributes that it forces to show as dates?

The other is that I am not able to handle this in a correct way with `System.DirectoryServices.Accountmanagment`. I have a class that extends `UserPrincipal` which works fine, but adding this new attribute won't work. It fails when I try to pass date and also if I pass long.

I feel I have done something wrong in the `AD` schema process, although I am not sure what it could be. I have tried googling around, but so far I haven't found any similar issues in any articles.

I am very scared to do something that will mess up my `AD` so I am asking here for some tips regarding this, especially with dates.

EDIT:

I did some more testing and I have a solution for the AccountManagment.UserPrincipal extension. Though it "feels" strange:

```
    public DateTime? MyCustomDate
    {
        get
        {

            object[] result = this.ExtensionGet("my-custom-date");
            if (result != null && result.Length > 0)
            {
                if (result[0].GetType() == typeof(string))
                {
                    long l = 0;
                    return (long.TryParse(result[0].ToString(), out l) ? DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(l) : (DateTime?)null);
                }
                else
                {
                    ActiveDs.IADsLargeInteger li = (ActiveDs.IADsLargeInteger)result[0];
                    return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(((long)li.HighPart << 32) + li.LowPart).ToLocalTime();
                }
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                ExtensionSet("my-custom-date", ((DateTime)value).ToFileTimeUtc().ToString());
            else
                ExtensionSet("my-custom-date", null);
        }
    }
```

I tried different approaches, but it seems only the ToString() method works.

So I basically got it working. Also, I tried this with extending the allready built-in property for accountExires. I get the exact same behaviour so I believe my property in AD is created correctly.

EDIT #2:
The type check in the getter section of the property is there for when the property value sits in memory, if it has been changed by the property it self by the setter. The value is no longer of type com, but string (obviously)

Answer (score 0):

As I have been working with this some more today, it seems my solution in the edit does the job.

public DateTime? MyCustomDate {
        get
        {

```
        object[] result = this.ExtensionGet("my-custom-date");
        if (result != null && result.Length > 0)
        {
            if (result[0].GetType() == typeof(string))
            {
                long l = 0;
                return (long.TryParse(result[0].ToString(), out l) ? DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(l) : (DateTime?)null);
            }
            else
            {
                ActiveDs.IADsLargeInteger li = (ActiveDs.IADsLargeInteger)result[0];
                return DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(((long)li.HighPart << 32) + li.LowPart).ToLocalTime();
            }
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
            ExtensionSet("my-custom-date", ((DateTime)value).ToFileTimeUtc().ToString());
        else
            ExtensionSet("my-custom-date", null);
    }
}
```